# Google maps generate link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google maps embedded in my website. Its has markers and when clicked, it displays the property information at the position. (infobox). 
Now the user wants the following functionality:

---

I search for a place , the map displays the place with properties. After I drag the map and get some other property, I would like to share this one to some body. can I get a link 
to share the dragged position?

---

I know we can get the link in maps.google.com . It changes whenever we drag.
But how to do it in our website? 
Is there a way in google maps api to get that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to events on the [`Map`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)

The `idle` event is particully useful, but can use say `bounds_changed` to get events while dragging (or even the `drag` event itself!).

In that event update whatever link you are talking about.

Comment: Use the bounds_changed event as barryhunter said. You'll have to generate the link though. The format is var url = "http://maps.google.com/?ll=" + map.getCenter().lat() + "," + map.getCenter().lng() + "&t=h&z=" + map.getZoom();